# SCIP compile and installation problems in linux

Tags: c++, linux, scip

I have been trying to compile and install SCIP under Linux but at the end of the compiling process appears the following error....

```
** Build complete.
** Find your SCIP binary in "/home/carloserwin/Documents/scipoptsuite-4.0.0/scip-4.0.0/bin".
** Enter "make test" to solve a number of easy instances in order to verify that SCIP runs correctly.

make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/carloserwin/Documents/scipoptsuite-4.0.0'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/carloserwin/Documents/scipoptsuite-4.0.0'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/carloserwin/Documents/scipoptsuite-4.0.0'
ar: /home/carloserwin/Documents/scipoptsuite-4.0.0/zimpl-3.3.4/obj/O.linux.x86.gnu.shared.opt/blkmem.o: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile.doit:238: scipoptlib] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/carloserwin/Documents/scipoptsuite-4.0.0'
make: *** [Makefile:98: scipoptlib] Error 2
```

when I write "make test", almost every test fails. After several attempts in Linux with no success, I tried to compile in Mac and it worked perfect, and all tests are ok. But I need to get it to work on Linux.

gcc version is 7-2.1
OS Linux openSUSE Tumbleweed, KDE 5.10.3
32-bit

Comment: Seems like it skipped compilation on a file. This could be a defect in that particular version. Have you tried others?

Comment: Can you provide the full build log? And can you run `make` and `make test` in the scip subdirectory?

Comment: Downloaded and installed version SCIP version 3.2.1 in linux without any problem. So there must be something strange with version 4.0.0. Thanks for the advise

Comment: @stefan I have the same problem and can provide the full build log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ef4b779dca2b50a4ac42d176b5a0a0bf I can also attest, that `make` and `make test` run without a hitch

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the scipoptlib makefile uses the wrong directory to look for the zimpl objects. There seems to be some fix in the internal development version, maybe it will help:

```
diff --git a/Makefile.doit b/Makefile.doit
index 344f0ee..1d8077e 100644
--- a/Makefile.doit
+++ b/Makefile.doit
@@ -65,7 +65,7 @@ ZIMPLOBJECTS =          blkmem.o bound.o code.o conname.o define.o elem.o entry.


 ifeq ($(ZIMPL),true)
-SCIPOPTOBJFILES    +=  $(addprefix $(ZIMPLDIR)/obj/O.$(OSTYPE).$(ARCH).$(COMP).shared.$(ZIMPLOPT)/,$(ZIMPLOBJECTS))
+SCIPOPTOBJFILES    +=  $(addprefix $(ZIMPLDIR)/obj/O.$(OSTYPE).$(ARCH).$(COMP).$(LIBTYPE).$(ZIMPLOPT)/,$(ZIMPLOBJECTS))
 endif

 ifeq ($(LIBBUILD),$(LINKCC))
```

Comment: I cannot accept this answer (as I'm not the poster), but I can attest it solves the problem on my machine. Have an upvote :)